# Creating a gradebook with the pandas module

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

So I have recently started teaching a course and wanted to handle my grades using python and the pandas module. For this class the students work in groups and turn in one assignment per table. I have a file with all of the students that is formatted like such

```
Name, Email, Table
"John Doe", jdoe@school.edu, 3
"Jane Doe", jane@gmail.com, 5
.
.
.
```

and another file with the grades for each table for the assignments done

```
Table, worksheet, another assignment, etc
1, 8, 15, 4
2, 9, 23, 5
3, 3, 20, 7
.
.
.
```

What I want to do is assign the appropriate grade to each student based on their table number. Here is what I have done

```
import pandas as pd

t_data = pd.read_csv('table_grades.csv')
roster = pd.read_csv('roster.csv')

for i in range(1, len(t_data.columns)):
    x = []
    for j in range(len(roster)):
        for k in range(len(t_data)): 
            if roster.Table.values[j] == k+1:
                x.append(t_data[t_data.columns.values[i]][k])
    roster[t_data.columns.values[i]] = x
```

Which does what I want but I feel like there must be a better way to do a task like this using the pandas. I am new to pandas and appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC -- unfortunately your code doesn't run for me with your data and you didn't give example output, so I can't be sure -- you're looking for `merge`.  Adding a new student, Fred Smith, to table 3:

```
In [182]: roster.merge(t_data, on="Table")
Out[182]: 
         Name               Email  Table  worksheet  another assignment  etc
0    John Doe     jdoe@school.edu      3          3                  20    7
1  Fred Smith  fsmith@example.com      3          3                  20    7

[2 rows x 6 columns]
```

or maybe an outer merge, to make it easier to spot missing/misaligned data:

```
In [183]: roster.merge(t_data, on="Table", how="outer")
Out[183]: 
         Name               Email  Table  worksheet  another assignment  etc
0    John Doe     jdoe@school.edu      3          3                  20    7
1  Fred Smith  fsmith@example.com      3          3                  20    7
2    Jane Doe      jane@gmail.com      5        NaN                 NaN  NaN
3         NaN                 NaN      1          8                  15    4
4         NaN                 NaN      2          9                  23    5

[5 rows x 6 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

roster = pd.read_csv(\
    StringIO("""Name,Email,Table
                'John Doe', jdoe@school.edu, 1
                'Jane Doe', jane@gmail.com, 3
                'Jack Doe', jack@gmail.com, 2"""))

t_data = pd.read_csv(\
    StringIO("""Table,worksheet,another assignment,etc
                1, 8, 15, 4
                2, 9, 23, 5
                3, 3, 20, 7"""))

roster=roster.set_index('Table')
res = pd.concat((roster.loc[t_data.Table].set_index(t_data.index), t_data), axis=1)
```

The result is

```
                         Name             Email  Table  worksheet  another assignment  etc
0                  'John Doe'   jdoe@school.edu      1          8                  15    4
1                  'Jack Doe'    jack@gmail.com      2          9                  23    5
2                  'Jane Doe'    jane@gmail.com      3          3                  20    7
```